# How do I use jQuery to read a file from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read a JSON file with jQuery:

```
       var listOfItems;
       $(function() {
            $.getJSON('myData.json', function(data) {
                listOfItems = data.items;
            });
        });
```

This is myData.json:

```
{
    {"source": "Microsoft", "target": "Amazon", "type": "licensing"},
    {"source": "Microsoft", "target": "HTC", "type": "licensing"},
    {"source": "Samsung", "target": "Apple", "type": "suit"},
    {"source": "Motorola", "target": "Apple", "type": "suit"}
}
```

However, Chrome Web Developer notes that `listOfItems` is undefined after this code. Why? I am sure that both the javascript, HTML, and JSON files lie in the same directory.

Comment: That's not a valid json response.

Comment: Thank you, I just fixed the JSON. I think the same error is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an asynchronous event. You can't perform a variable assignment like that with an asynchronous event, you must perform whatever operation you're doing within that specific function. Otherwise make sure it's a synchronous event (by setting the correct variable in JQuery), which will wait for the operation, in this case, the GET-request to complete before continuing the code (which is not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

Fix the JSON. [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) will tell you what is wrong.

Property names in JSON are strings (unlike JavaScript where they may be identifiers) so they must be *quoted*.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that you use an "{" instead of "[" for the containing array

You should have

```
[
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "Amazon", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Microsoft", target: "HTC", type: "licensing"},
    {source: "Samsung", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
    {source: "Motorola", target: "Apple", type: "suit"},
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `myData.json` is not valid JSON.

It appears to contain an Object, which itself contains four Objects - but those inner objects haven't been given property names.

This would be valid

```
{
    "one"   : { "source":  "Microsoft", "target" : "Amazon", "type" : "licensing" },
    "two"   : { "source" : "Microsoft", "target" : "HTC",    "type" : "licensing" },
    "three" : { "source" : "Samsung",   "target" : "Apple",  "type" : "suit" },
    "four"  : { "source" : "Motorola",  "target" : "Apple",  "type" : "suit" }
}
```

But, given your `listOfItems`, I don't think that's what you want. You probably want an Array of Objects.

This is done by using square brackets instead of braces

```
[
    { "source":  "Microsoft", "target" : "Amazon", "type" : "licensing" },
    { "source" : "Microsoft", "target" : "HTC",    "type" : "licensing" },
    { "source" : "Samsung",   "target" : "Apple",  "type" : "suit" },
    { "source" : "Motorola",  "target" : "Apple",  "type" : "suit" }
]
```

Also, watch out for that trailing comma on the final item. It breaks in some browsers / javascript engines.  I don't know offhand if JSON parsers allow it or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the json with jQuery.parseJSON();

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Passing in a malformed JSON string may result in an exception being thrown. For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:

```
{test: 1} (test does not have double quotes around it).
{'test': 1} ('test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes).
```

Additionally if you pass in nothing, an empty string, null, or undefined, 'null' will be returned from parseJSON. Where the browser provides a native implementation of JSON.parse, jQuery uses it to parse the string. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.